# How to shuffle the images in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to know how to shuffle the images.If i drag an image into another image place then those images have to shuffle
                   Thanks in advance

Comment: Shuffle how? Do you want to randomly display an image in an UIImageView, or what? Be more specific.

Comment: are you looking for a 'springboard-like' functionality (moving the app-icons around)?

Comment: yes it is just like a spring board functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : https://github.com/sync/AQGridView